# Xorg display issue in a newly installed RHEL6 machine

Tags: xorg

I installed **RHEL6** in a pretty old machine. The installation went perfectly fine and after installation, I did the below steps.

- Registered the machine with the satellite.
- Ran the `yum update` command to receive the latest updates for this machine.

The above 2 steps went on perfectly fine. Now, after configuring the firewall and network as a routine step, I restarted the machine.

Now, the machine is stuck in the *RHEL6 symbol page*. It is neither going to the login page nor allowing me to login to the text mode. However, ssh to this machine is working fine.

So, I checked the `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in 2 machines. (First machine has perfectly working X server and the second machine is the one where it is stuck in RHEL6 symbol).

I found couple of warnings like below in the faulty machine.

```
[   102.453] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setpgid failed: Operation not permitted
[   102.453] (WW) xf86OpenConsole: setsid failed: Operation not permitted
```

Also, in the faulty machine, my log abruptly ends at this line.

```
[    102.718] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 338 x 270
```

However, in the working machine, after the above log message I see that keyboard registry and other things are being recorded in the log.

So, where is the problem in this newly installed machine? Is it a driver issue? Or is it something related to corrupted hard disk? How should I resolve this?

I tried the below step but it is not working.

`X -configure` which gave me the error as,

```
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 1):

I propose the following that you restart your machine, on boot there is progress bar in bottom of screen. When it starts to fill press escape (ESC), in that way you'll get boot process by deamon.

And then tell me if there is the step which hangs, eg:

```
Starting atd:     [OK]
```

If had the similar problem and I resolved it by entering into RUN-LEVEL 3 and installing this packages:

```
yum -y groupinstall 'Desktop' 'Desktop Platform' 'X Window System' 'Fonts'
```

This resolved some of my dependencies issues.

Comment: sounds interesting. Let me check if this resolves my issue. :)